# Minimum n in order to have at least C combinations of order r?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

I am a bit stuck on this problem. How do I find the minimum number of elements ***n*** which ensure that I have at least ***C*** combinations of order ***r*** ? Basically, for a given ***C*** and ***r***, find the minimum ***n*** which satisfies:

> $\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!} \ge C$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: stirling approximation of the binomial coefficient may help here